Is it possible to remote control/screen share a specific virtual tty on KDE Plasma Wayland?
I am on KDE Plasma, Kwin (Wayland), Arch based distro (Endeavour).
I use tty1, and want my friend to login to e.g. tty2, start up plasmashell, and then remote-in/stream specifically tty2 to e.g their laptop. This way I can use my computer in my tty1, and they can simultaneously e.g. watch videos/play games on their tty2 using my system's resources.
Normally, I would try something with X servers or tigervnc perhaps, but that's not available on wayland systems.
I tried moonlight/sunshine but that seems to stream the current display, and the control is shared (e.g. current on screen mouse always moves).
Is this functionality even presently possible, and if so, how could one achieve this?

as written, not possible, because tty1 and tty2 are the terminals "physically" located on your keyboard, if you will. But I think your console mentioning is honestly just a distraction, as it doesn't matter to you.  what you really care about: remote desktop with a KDE Plasma desktop on Wayland, with the remoted-in session not being in charge of the screen. Would that interpretation of your question reflect what you want?

I believe so, yes. If my session is in charge of the screen, and the remoted in session is not, (but still e.g. has a remote view/controls) then I imagine that would work, assuming the controls are appropriately split up.

Have you tried wayvnc ?

I have not, but checking out it's page, the first thing I see is "This is a VNC server for wlroots-based Wayland compositors (⛔ Gnome, KDE and Weston are not supported).", so unfortunately it will not work. Thank you anyway :)

I don't think that "logging in locally, then letting someone else take over the local seat and then loggingin remotely" will work out; too many things would need to "bend over" to the remote target.
However, why not do the remote thing from the start, and then, if you want to (surprisingly) use the machine locally, locally log in using the same access software as you'd use remote?
If that seems a thing worth considering:  Sunshine might be what you want: a remote server for the Moonlight game streaming protocol.
Your friend would log in (but not locally, if they need to access things remotely, anyways: SSH log in would totally do), and start the Sunshine server. The trick there is making the display system think there's another screen connected, that's not actually there; that would allow you to start an X server (I think starting a wayland compositor would work as well, but of course the trickery would have to look different) and then launch any program you'd want on that.
